Mailbox Filtering by Body Content Also Captures Subject Matches
I have a method that filters emails from an Outlook mailbox based on the sender and optionally, the subject and the body content (either or both). I'm using the exchangelib library to access the Exchange server.
Below is a simplified version of my code:
from exchangelib import Account, Credentials, Q
from typing import Literal


class EmailClient:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.receiver_email = "mymail@email.com"
        self.receiver_un = "username"
        self.receiver_pw = "password"

    def filter_inbox(self, 
                     sender_address: str,
                     required_subj_part: str = "",
                     required_body_part: str = "",
                     both_operator: Literal["or", "and"] = "or") -> None:

        subj_query = Q(subject__contains=required_subj_part)
        body_query = Q(body__contains=required_body_part)

        if required_subj_part and required_body_part:
            if both_operator == "or":
                query = subj_query | body_query
            elif both_operator == "and":
                query = subj_query & body_query
            else:
                raise ValueError("'both_operator' must be one of: 'or', 'and'")

        elif required_subj_part:
            query = subj_query

        elif required_body_part:
            query = body_query

        else:
            query = Q()

        account = Account(self.receiver_email, autodiscover=True, 
                          credentials=Credentials(self.receiver_un, self.receiver_pw))

        for item in account.inbox.filter(query, sender=sender_address):
            subject = item.subject
            body = item.body.strip()

            print(f"{subject=}")
            print(f"{body=}", end="\n\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ec = EmailClient()
    body_filter = "BBB"

    ec.filter_inbox("sender@email.com", required_body_part=body_filter)

I'm facing an issue where filtering emails based only on the body content also includes results that match the subject.
For instance, I have 3 mails in the inbox related to the sender:

Subject: 'AAA BBB' | Body: 'AAA BBB'
Subject: 'BBB' | Body: 'AAA'
Subject: 'AAA' | Body: 'BBB'

Even though email number 2 does not contain 'BBB' in its body, it is still included in the results of the filtering (because it has 'BBB' in the subject). Moreover, when I filter based only on the subject, it works as expected, indicating that the issue is likely related to filtering only the body content.
Is there a way to ensure that the filtering applies only to the body when that is the only specified criterion?
Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I don't know exchangelib but maybe it has operator "not". In documentation I see qs.filter(subject__not="foo")

in other example I see qs.filter(subject__contains="foo") and later I see ~Q(..) which probably uses ~ as not - so it could be ~Q(qs.filter(subject__contains="BBB") to get not contains

@furas Thank you for trying to help. However, it has nothing to do with what the subject does not contain. It doesn't matter if the subject does or does not contain the same word, the main thing is that the body content of the email does.
This is also the case when I filter by word in the subject, it doesn't matter that the word also appears in the body of the email, the main thing is that it is included in the subject

but you  have problem with subject - so you can use filter body contains BBB and subject not contains BBB. OR maybe first  you have to use print() to see if code runs correct query.

@furas If the body contains "BBB" and the subject also contains "BBB" then I want it to be included in the results because it doesn't matter what is in the subject as long as the body contains what I was looked for. Therefore it doesn't make sense to add to the query that the subjet would not contain "BBB"

then maybe you have something wrong in if/else - maybe you create wrong query with or. Did you use print() if you generate correct query? Did you try to reduce all query  to Q(body__contains=required_body_part) ? I don't use Outlook so I can't test it and I have no other ideas what can makes problem. Maybe Outlook doesn't have this function and you will have to filter mails after getting from server
